# Extremum of a function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, slope

I want to know whether it is possible that a point be an extremum without the derivative at that point being zero ?

I encountered this point when reading about the fact that entropy maximizes as function of energy but we know that $1/T=\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}$ (assuming Entropy is smooth and differentiable in the desired domain) which would make temperature infinite.

I already read a similar post on Physics Stackexchange but didn't get satisfactory answer.

Comment: It is possible for say $f(x) = e^{x}; 0 \leq x \leq 5$. So the extremum of the function is $e^{5}$ which is attained at $x = 5$, but the derivative of the function at $x = 5$ is not zero.

Comment: Oh ! So in a sense if this condition is to hold then extremum should occur at the end points. Right ?

Comment: My example is the case of a _non-decreasing_ function, so that's why the extremum occurs at the end-point. Similarly, for a decreasing function, the extremum should occur at the initial point. If the function is neither increasing nor decreasing, then the derivative at extremum should be zero.

Comment: there are non differentiable functions, you might want to exclude them in your post

Comment: @qbert, did it.

Comment: " the fact that entropy maximizes as function of energy "  Does that mean what we think it means?  I suspect (but do not know) that a non-mathematician physicist wrote these and meant that entropy is bounded above and has a supreme value that is never actually met.  Maybe.

Comment: Hmm.... I was wrong in that comment.

Comment: I think its something like this, for a given energy the system achieves the state with maximum entropy (I think this is what is meant by entropy maximization) and if you increase the energy, the new value of entropy will not only be the maximum with respect to that energy but it also be greater than the previous value of entropy.

Comment: So, from your comments I understood that the entropy maximization is a constrained optimization problem, which will have extremum either at critical (derivative is zero) or boundary points.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, if your domain is compact with boundary or has a discontinuity: for the easiest example, think of a graph of a straight line y=x on $0 \leq x \leq 10$ having a maximum at (10, 10) and a minimum at (0,0).

If there's a discontinuity in the domain or the range (far more treacherous), an extremum could occur there (again, the graph of the function would 'break off' and continue elsewhere).

Comment: Comments on my question and your answer and one more sum up to the point that entropy extremum should occur at the ends as Entropy is an increasing function of energy. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it. ALSO, the discontinuity in a derivative is also a way out of it: $y=|x|$ for example: there, the discontinuity is in the first derivative.

Comment: @OmgHomology That function isn't differentiable at x=0 and the first derivative is in fact continuous.

Answer (score 0):

More ever of the points that derivative is equal to zero the the span boundaries also should be considered as critical points

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out another example, to add to all of this.
The absolute value function does not have a definite value for the derivative at the Origin (the extremum), as the relevant limit does not exist at said point.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = |x|$.  It has a minimum at $x= 0$, but the derivative isn't $0$ at $x=0$.  Or consider the function $g:[-1,2]\to [0,4]$ via $g(x) = x^2$.  It has a maximum at $x=2$ but $g'(2) = 4$.

These are exceptions of course.  If $f$ is continuous, differentiable and $x$ is not an extreme point of a compact domain then an extremum and $x$ would imply that the derivative at $x$ is zero.  That should be easy to show by definitions.  (Intuitively if the derivative is positive or negative, the function is increasing or decreasing which means there will be points before and after which are larger on one side and smaller on the other.)